# Calculating Lyapunov exponent (LE) for pendulum using ellipsoid growth - code yields negative LEs

Tags: computational-physics, software, chaos-theory, complex-systems

Per my advisor, I have read the textbook *Chaos, an introduction to dynamical systems* by Alligood, Sauer, and Yorke. (side not, I have really enjoyed this book). In chapter 5, the numerical calculation of Lyapunov exponents (LE) is given where you track the growth of the ellipsoid using the Jacobian of the system and Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. Example 5.6 asks one to determine the LEs for the Henon map with parameters a = 1.4 and b = 0.3 using this method, noting one should expect to receive LEs of h1 = 0.42 and h2 = -1.62, respectively, for the dimensions x and y. I have successfully done this in Matlab so I know the code works.

My issue is that when I try to apply this to the forced, damped pendulum, I output negative LEs when input parameters should yield chaotic behavior. I have used the equations from [My physics pendulum](https://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum/chaotic-pendulum-en.html) so I know what parameters should yield this chaotic behavior (assuming this site evaluated it accurately). It is solved using ODE45. The initial conditions I input are random.

The inputs for the Jacobian I use are those that result from the *time-2pi* map. When that failed, I tried using data for every iteration instead. Bust.

According to the site and my code, I should be seeing a positive LE, but both I get are negative. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure that link is correct? There is a point where it goes clockwise around to about the 2 o'clock position, stops and then rotates *counter-clockwise*. Even for a chaotic pendulum, that seems *very* wrong.

Comment: @KyleKanos It's a forced pendulum. The forcing is indicated by the curved arrow in the plot.

Comment: t-osu I'm not sure there's enough information to answer your question: we'd need to see your code and results to answer properly — but then the question is off-topic ([Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might then be a better home for it). Generic advice I could give is to perform sanity checks: does it behave reasonably in the extreme and especial cases (zero damping; zero forcing, very high damping, etc.)? Is energy preserved for zero damping and force simultaneously? Phase space plots look reasonable?

Comment: @stafusa , thanks. I have done many double checks on sensitivity to IC, topological transitivity, dense periodic orbits, and poincare plots. I didn't really want to get into all that b/c my post would be so long. I was thinking of uploading my code somehow, but didn't think that would be appropriate for this forum. I will try the forum you mentioned and hopefully be able to answer my own question in the future :]

Comment: @stafusa ah, that makes sense now. I probably should read more of links :|